# Weird reputation drop in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, reputation

Just yesterday I had 128 reputation which I remember quite clearly. I know it happened because I got the "vote down" privilege. But today, when I see my reputation, it is 113. Going to my user page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8648710/neel-g) I see that I have not suffered *any* reputation downvote.

On further digging, where I expected the reputation chart to steadily go up to 128 it only goes up to 128. I thought that I should review some of my previous answers to find that the recent most I could remember still exist (with or without a downvote). Even my messages don't show me about some drop. Can anyone explain why this weird drop happened? It is like the reputation actually disappeared overnight!

Note that the big drop in the chart is due to posting a bounty...

Comment: I bet someone accepted one of your answers yesterday, so you saw +15 and 128. But then later, they unaccepted (and maybe accepted a different answer) *the same day*. Accepts/unaccepts in the same day are not preserved in the log. Happens all the time to frequent answerers.

Comment: I certainly considered that, but from my examination I do not notice if something has happened to any of my answers. SO should tell me about it, so that I may enquire why my answer was not appropriate for the OP. How will I gain feedback then? this is really wrong :(

Comment: Yeah, if OP accepts, you don't memorize the post the rep gain was for, but then OP retracts it, there's no way for you to identify which post it was on. *Usually* in this situation, it's because OP decided to accept a different answer, which is normal enough and isn't bad. (occasionally this occurs because they don't clearly see the difference between the brown checkmark and the green checkmark, though, and accidentally unaccepted when they thought they hadn't accepted it yet - this has happened quite a few times)

Comment: @CertainPerformance lol :) So I guess I should just leave it alone and go earn some more rep. Thanx a lot!

Comment: @neelg don't sweat the small stuff. Remember that when you contribute answers you're doing it for *everyone* not just the person that asked it. If they move the "accepted" around a bit - such is life. Just don't get too hung up on that - it's certainly frustrating but does happen.

Comment: @JonClements I guess I don't care, but Machine Learning tag has so many dummies that getting a question that is not downvoted or closed is a miracle equivalent to Jesus' rebirth. So the chances of earning rep are lessened. But no problem, I will surely move on. Thanx for the assurance tho!

Comment: @neelg you seem to be quite concerned with rep? it's really not that important. Write good answers to questions you're knowledgeable in and it'll come naturally - don't get hung up on the "I'll only answer something if I can see my imaginary internet points go up" thing.

Comment: @JonClements I agree. it is just I wish there was some dedicated moderator for ML tag. There are too many negative and dumb questions that are not closed. The only one I actually see is 'desertanut'... ML comunity is growing fast but without moderators the forum is doomed..

Comment: Questions like this {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299245/is-it-possible-to-read-thermal-image-from-normal-camera-using-opencv} how are they even RELATED to ML? We need someone to curate all this stuff....

Comment: @neelg use your votes accordingly - if it's good - give it an upvote, if it's not useful then downvote but consider if you can make an edit to it to make it good without destroying the OP's intention/original code, and you can always flag it for "closure" that'll give others that frequent the review queues to take a look and decide if it should be put on hold until the OP elaborates for instance

Comment: The subject of low quality around machine learning questions has been lifted multiple times here on Meta, but the problem is always that this depends on the community's willingness to curate them. Without enough curators visiting those tags, those low quality posts will be "off radar".

Comment: Related (cross site, about machine learning questions in particular, and same OP): *[No minimum question limit on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346705)* - *"...surprised by how short the questions are becoming in that place. ML is fast growing, but there isn't any moderator to close down or remove posts on that tag."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Well, the question was actually posted by me, if you didn't know :) also I agree with E_net4 but seeing the no. of posters on the forum, We should assume that there are that many answerers too. Sure not all of them have enough knowledge and are only beginners but at least they can identify those non ML questions. But I guess ours is a young community and it needs time to mature....